# How to undo a wordpress site from Multi-site to stand-alone Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

I am considering creating a new Wordpress multi-site network.

My question is...
Say down the road, I need to separate a site from the multi-site network to become a stand-alone site that can be moved to another server, etc. How feasible is this and could you give a quick rundown for how involved this would be to accomplish? Obstacles?

Thank you in advance for your help-

Answer (score 0):

Export the site, just like a single site. See [Tools Export Screen « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_SubPanel)